# List audio input devices - VBA

Tags: winapi, ms-access, vba, audio

I have a bit of a complex Access Database that I need to do some audio recording with. I have nearly everything working using outside solutions but I am forced to select my input device from within Access.

All that I need is some way to get a collection of devices or something from Windows and I can take it from there. http://www.vbmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vb/32848/listing-all-audio-devices does something close to what I am looking for except that is the output instead of the input. I know that there will be no extremely easy way to accomplish this but I know it is possible, I just can't seem to find how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, not the easiest question :-) I think you indeed need to invoke a native function.

Maby something like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645598(v=vs.85).aspx

VB implementation in the bottom.
Good luck!

Comment: I can't figure out why it is so hard! Basically every piece of software that does any sort of recording needs to have the functionality to select what the input device is going to be. This really isn't any different.

Comment: Is the declaration in VB.Net (VB 9)?

Comment: It doesn't look any harder than any Windows API call. You should be grateful that you're working with a development platform that makes it possible to extend functionality by using Windows API calls. I don't know that any comparable database development tool can do this (the only tools truly comparable to Access are FileMaker Pro and OpenOffice Base). I'd be interested to hear if they can.

Comment: I'm not afraid of Windows API calls, I just can't seem to find an example or documentation on what they are and how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

The code you linked creates a SWbemObjectSet, then lists properties of its members (sound devices).  From what I can tell, you want that object but don't want to list the properties ("output").

If that is correct, create a function which strips away the output statements and just returns the SWbemObjectSet object.

```
Public Function getSoundDevices(Optional strComputer As String = ".") As Object
    Const cstrQuery As String = "Select * from Win32_SoundDevice"
    Dim objWMIService As Object 'TypeName = SWbemServicesEx '

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set getSoundDevices = objWMIService.ExecQuery(cstrQuery, , 48)
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
End Function
```

Then call the function to use the SWbemObjectSet as input for your other code.

```
Public Sub test_getSoundDevices()
    Dim objSoundDevices As Object 'TypeName = SWbemObjectSet '
    Dim objDevice As Object 'TypeName = SWbemObjectEx '
    Set objSoundDevices = getSoundDevices()
    For Each objDevice In objSoundDevices
        '* do what you want for each sound device here *'
        Debug.Print "ProductName: " & objDevice.ProductName
    Next objDevice
    Set objDevice = Nothing
    Set objSoundDevices = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This lists the sound cards on my system. That isn't what I need. What I need is to list the input ports physically on the sound card such as microphone, line in etc.